# Space Complexity of Constants

Tags: c++, space-complexity

I'm reading a book in which I found a weird example of space complexity.
It says there's a function.

```
int sum(int a[],int n)
{
 int s=0;
 for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
 s+=a[i];
 }
return s;
```

It says that the total space complexity of this problem is 10 bytes.

```
a - 2 bytes
n - 2 bytes
s - 2 bytes
i - 2 bytes
0 - 2 bytes from (i=0)
```

My question is if `0` from `i=0` has 2 bytes of space then shouldn't the `0` from `s=0` should also take up 2 bytes.
And in some later questions it doesn't even consider constants for space complexity.

Can you please tell if this is some mistake or some kind of method.

I also tried google, but I couldn't get anything satisfying.

Comment: `space complexity of this problem is 10 bytes` This makes little sense - complexity estimates don't work this way. Absolute values don't matter - what matters is [how fast space requirements grow with the size of the input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity). `sum()` is said to have `O(1)` (constant) space complexity and `O(n)` (linear) time complexity.

Comment: Give us the title and author of the book.